# How to fetch cursor values from pivot SQL to fixed variables - Error ORA-01007

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL statement with the PIVOT operation. The maximum number of columns I will have in PIVOT is 5, but I can have less, 4, 3, 2.
How can I read these columns in my cursor and assign (fetch .. into...) to the fixed variables, without occurring the error ORA-01007.

```
...
sql_stmt := 'select * from 
                (select codcoligada, 
                        idprd, 
                        codcfo, 
                        valnegociado 
                 from tcitmorcamento 
                 where codcoligada = ' || p_codcoligada || ' 
                   and codcotacao = ' || '''' || p_codcotacao || '''' || ') 
                 pivot 
                 (
                   sum(valnegociado) for codcfo in (' || pivot_clause || ')
                 )';

  ret  := t_tab_sesa_cotacao();

  open vCursor for sql_stmt; 

  loop
    /* If my cursor returns less than 5 columns in PIVOT the error occurs ORA-01007 */ 
    fetch vCursor into vCodColigada, vIdProduto, vValor01, vValor02, vValor03, vValor04, vValor05;
    exit when vCursor%NOTFOUND;
      ret.extend;
      ret(ret.count) := t_type_sesa_cotacao(vCodColigada, vIdProduto, vValor01, vValor02, vValor03, vValor04, vValor05);
  end loop;

  close vCursor;
...
```

If I return less than 5 colums, I want to fill in the remainder of the variables with a value of 0 or null.

The variables vCodColigada and vIdProduto are identified, only PIVOT columns that can vary between 1 and 5 (vValor1, vValor2, vValor3, vValor4, vValor5)

Result PIVOT SQL:

```
CODCOLIGADA       IDPRD            '000125'         '002272'         '002342'         
----------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
                1            15464               45              300               30 
                1            18460               35              200               20 
                1            57492               20              100               10 
-------- End of Data --------
```

Example:
If the cursor returns 3 values in the PIVOT (above), the variables vValor01, vValor02, vValor03 will be filled in, and the variables vValor04, vValor05 must be 0 or null.

Example:

```
CODCOLIGADA       IDPRD            VALOR01          VALOR02          VALOR03          VALOR04          VALOR05          
----------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
                1            15464               45              300               30                0                0 
                1            18460               35              200               20                0                0 
                1            57492               20              100               10                0                0 
-------- End of Data --------
```

As I only have 3 columns in PIVOT, and I have 5 variables, the ORA-01007 error occurs in (fetch .. into ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this below snippet helps. What the basic understanding is we need to add excess variable as null or blank to make this work.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv_pivot VARCHAR2(100):='''Y'',''N''';
TYPE lv
IS
  RECORD
  (
    flg_y VARCHAR2(100),
    flg_n VARCHAR2(100),
    flg_e VARCHAR2(100));
type lv_tab
IS
  TABLE OF lv;
  lv_num lv_tab;
  lv_check VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  lv_check   :=regexp_count(lv_pivot,',',1);
  IF lv_check < 3 THEN
    FOR z IN 1..(2-lv_check)
    LOOP
      lv_pivot:=lv_pivot||',null as val'||z;
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    lv_pivot:=lv_pivot;
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_pivot);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT * FROM                         
(SELECT col1 FROM <table>  )                       
pivot ( COUNT(1) FOR col1 IN ('||lv_pivot||'))' BULK COLLECT INTO lv_num;
END;


---------------------------Refactoring in Function------------------------------

--Create Object Type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lv_obj IS OBJECT
(
        flg_y VARCHAR2(100),
        flg_n VARCHAR2(100),
        flg_e VARCHAR2(100)
);

--Create Table Type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lv_tab IS TABLE OF lv_obj;

--Create Function
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION test_func
    RETURN lv_tab
  AS
    lv_pivot VARCHAR2(100):='''Y'',''N''';
    lv_num lv_tab;
    lv_check VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN
    lv_check   :=regexp_count(lv_pivot,',',1);
    IF lv_check < 3 THEN
      FOR z IN 1..(2-lv_check)
      LOOP
        lv_pivot:=lv_pivot||',null as val'||z;
      END LOOP;
    ELSE
      lv_pivot:=lv_pivot;
    END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_pivot);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT * FROM                         
(SELECT col1 FROM <table>  )                       
pivot ( COUNT(1) FOR col1 IN ('||lv_pivot||'))' BULK COLLECT INTO lv_num;
    RETURN lv_tab;
  END;

-------------------------------------------------Output-----------------------------------------------

SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_func);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked. How could I return this type (lv_num) by a function?

Comment: I have refactored the output in Function. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for help. This error occurs: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -

Comment: It would have to be this way: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT lv_object(flg_y, flg_n, flg_e ) FROM (SELECT * FROM                         
(SELECT col1 FROM <table>  )                       
pivot ( COUNT(1) FOR col1 IN ('||lv_pivot||')))' BULK COLLECT INTO lv_num; But, PIVOT return columns dinamically. Do not know the name of the columns in lv_pivot.

Answer (score -1):

Try padding the results in the query.  Add a join to a select from dual statement that passes back all five columns.

Comment: Please. Could you give an example?